# Does voltage or current matter most when setting up an efficient water electrolyzer?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis, electricity

I am setting up a homemade water electrolyzer for producing hydrogen gas, which will solely be used by myself for experimental purposes, and have heard the wattage used has a large part to play in determining efficiency. However, seeing as watts are determined by Voltage * Current, would high-voltage-low-current or low-voltage-high-current lead to the production of more gas?

Comment: The amount of Hydrogen gas collected at the electrode depends only upon the current, in A. The voltage has no direct effect. It may be used to increase the current, that is all.

Comment: You can't necessarily take a setup that runs at 10V @ 2A and get it to run at 2V @ 10A. Things such as electrode size, distance between electrodes, electrolyte, and stirring have an effect on the operation of a real cell. // I'll point out that the cell will effectively have an internal resistance. The more current, the more power is lost to heat.

Comment: @MaxW I would strike "not necessarily " and say *definitely not*.

Answer (score 2):

The cell run at 10V / 2A will definitely produce much less hydrogen. Exactly a fifth, if the numbers were true. The amount of gas produced is directly proportional to the current. Current x time / Faraday´s constant / 2 gives the molar amount of hydrogen. All voltage applied that is more than the nominal voltage necessary to run the electrolysis produces just heat.

Of course at two volts, the electrolysis will in reality hardly run at all. A few milliamperes with the same cell. Highly efficient, but extremely slow. There is some optimum in between. Where it is depends your special setup and your own preferences.

If you want as much hydrogen generation capacity as possible, you can choose between buying more (or larger) cells, or turning a lot of electricity into heat in the long run.

Comment: I am using a 12V 10AH LiFePO4 battery in conjunction with a 100W monocrystalline solar cell as the energy source; I apologize for neglecting to mention that. Do you think you could explain what calculations might be necessary to find such an optimum range as you mentioned?

Comment: The math is not exactly difficult. The unloaded cell voltage is around 2V, the rest of the cell resistance is more or less ohmic. Measure the current at e.g. 5V, and you have all numbers that are necessary for a rough approximation.

Answer (score 2):

There are few things to consider:

1. The rate of hydrogen production is proportional to the passing current.
2. For voltage below cca 1.8-2.0 V, the current is very low.
3. Above that value, the current quickly grows ( in first like exponentially, later more linearly ).
4. The current for high enough voltage depends on the electrolyzer geometry, electrolyte conductivity and temperature. For electrodes with larger areas, closer each other, the current for given voltage is higher. The same for higher conductivity or temperature.
5. Set electrode current density low enough to prolong their life.
6. The electrolysis efficiency decreases  for higher voltages, because part of the voltage is wasted on warming up the solution.
7. For production, it is good to manage an electronic high power constant current source, the best with the electronic max voltage control, as keeping the  given reasonable current  is more important than a needed particular voltage, that would vary. The alternative is the obvious, more common voltage source with the electronic max current control.

Comment: I object to your point 7: If the current drops noticeably for a given voltage, that means something is changing in your cell, and most likely not for the better. In which case increasing the voltage is the last thing you should do.

Comment: I mean an  intelligent current source with the voltage check, similarly as voltage sources have the current check. I had in mind the voltage drifts depending on temperature or concentration.

Comment: Depends. A temperature increase *should* lower the electrolyte resistance, hence the voltage would drop for a constant current, which is good. *If* that initial assumption is true. If not, you blow up your cell. If the electrolyte concentration changes, something is obviously wrong. It´s not directly obvious to me wether keeping the current and thereby hydrogen generation constant would help or make the situation worse. So yea, you need some "intelligent" control system. Which should also check the temperature, perhaps conductivity of inflowing/outflowing electrolyte, etc.

Comment: You may did not read the answer update...

Comment: @Poutnik An excellent point. I am wondering now if using an Arduino board with a thermal resistor of some sort may be an adequate temperature control system as they can be used for, among other things, the regulation of both temperature and voltage. The part about inflowing/outflowing electrolyte may not be necessary, however; my former chemistry teacher recommended Na2SO4, stating that once introduced, it may not need to be replenished due to both the sodium and sulfate ions being good electrical conductors.